# Unit coverage for Lambda expresssion in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to cover method which looks like

```
  protected SessionBuilderConfigurer getSessionBuilderConfigurer() {
    return cqlSessionBuilder -> {
        ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder programmaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder;
   
        programmaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder = getCassandraWithoutSslConfiguration();//Local method

        DriverConfigLoader driverConfigLoader = programmaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder.build();
        return cqlSessionBuilder
            .withConfigLoader(driverConfigLoader)
            .withAuthCredentials(properties.getUsername(), properties.getPassword());
    };
  }
```

This is not at all getting covered in JUnit.

JUnit:

```
//Class level
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

@InjectMocks WaausCassandraConfiguration configuration;


//Inside method
Assertions.assertNotNull(configuration.getSessionBuilderConfigurer());
```

Comment: From what you've posted it's not possible to tell a) what you are testing and b) if that lambda is getting called

Comment: @possum -  I am just trying to cover this method in unit testing.

Comment: Yes, you stated that.  You have not provided enough information to be helped.  If you're asking if lambdas can be included in test coverage, the answer is yes.

Comment: Also I see you keep asking this question.  Please close it and look for a response in the original.

Comment: @possum - I think you are not getting my question, it simple when I am writing JUnit for this method then that lambda expression is not getting called.

Comment: I am getting your quesiton and I'm telling you you need post your test if you want help.

Comment: You've shown code to call the method, but not shown any code which calls the lambda returned by that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getSessionBuilderConfigurer()` creates a `SessionBuilderConfigurer` object with the lambda is the implementation of some method (possibly [`SessionBuilderConfigurer.configure()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/config/SessionBuilderConfigurer.html#configure(com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSessionBuilder))).

If you want to execute the code in the lambda you need to execute that method:

```
CqlSessionBuilder sessionBuilder = mock(CqlSessionBuilder.class);
// the following line create the SessionBuilderConfigurer
SessionBuilderConfigurer configurer = configuration.getSessionBuilderConfigurer();
// the following line calls the lambda
configurer.configure(sessionBuilder);

// now you need to assert that the correct methods on the sessionBuilder have been called
```

Comment: I was not catching return SessionBuilderConfigurer, I was thinking it should get called while calling method.